# Windows 8.1 Tabs & Windows with webview

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, tabs, windows-8.1

When navigating using the webview in a Windows Store app any links which try to open in a new tab/windows or opened in internet explorer thus practically pulling users from my app. is there any way to handle the link event to either force the links to open in current view or a way to run code to create a new tab within my own app. i have had a look around and can't seem to see much in the way of a defined way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook up to the WebViews "NavigationStarting" event.
The you can cancel the navigation and reissue it from within your code so it navigates inside the webview.

Xaml:

```
    <WebView NavigationStarting="WebView_NavigationStarting" />
```

Codebehind:

```
    private void WebView_NavigationStarting(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationStartingEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Uri != null)
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
            sender.Navigate(args.Uri);
        }
    }
```

But you will loose the ability to open links in new windows completely, as you only have the uri itself available in the event handler.
Uri will be null if you use the NavigateToString operations on the webview.

Comment: First, this solution will be an infinite loop. Also the NavigationStarting event will not fire for an <a> element with target _blank.